# Template engine - regex, DOMDocument and xpath or something else?

Tags: php, regex, xpath, domdocument

I was thinking about the best way possible to parse templates with PHP by creating a template engine. The templates may contain HTML, CSS and JavaScript - but no PHP code. I know, there are plenty of engines out there... but I want to try to build my own one.

Here's a simple template file example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{printtitle/}</title>
<head>

<body>
   {hello attribute="world"/} <!-- template tags could contain attributes -->

   <!-- written as below should return the div within the tags. -->
   {innerhtml} 
     <div class="someclass">Some content</div>
   {/innerhtml}
</body>
</html>
```

I've read and seen examples on how to successfully parse template tags like the ones above with regular expressions. But, reading comments about those solutions made me think that the regular expressions to create a simple custom template engine is not the way to go. But I never figured out the reason for that. Too slow?

I am not very familiar with DOMDocument and Xpath. But is this a more modern approach to parse HTML templates as in the example above?

I appriciate some clarification to make me choose the right path here.

Comment: Just to put my two cents in: a way with regular expressions and some class functions in PHP would probably work. But why not use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), etc.? Additionally, should the `{innerhtml}` part be replaced as well?

Comment: Another comment: would you like to replace sth. (as in `{printtitle/}`) or to actually get some values out of the template (`{innerhtml}`)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Tags that are not self closed should return the innerhtml between the opening tag and the close tag. Of course, there can be more elements than one within these tags and they should be able to contain other template tags as well. As I said, I want to create my own engine. I've read good things about Smarty and I'm sure it would do the trick.. but I find this interessting and would enjoy program it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a custom document format / language, so DOMDocument, Xpath, or other pre-defined parsers are out of the question.  The answer depends on your requirements.

If your template language is simply replacing template markers with values, *and does not allow nesting*, regular expressions will be simple to implement and work well.

If your templates will have anything more elaborate, like loops, function calls, or nesting, you will want to formally define your rules with a lexer, such as [Phlexy](https://github.com/nikic/Phlexy).